# Definition of line in C using collinearity and complex scalar product

Tags: complex-analysis

The starting point is the definition of a line in $\mathbb{C}$ through $a$ and $b$ as the points $z$ such that the angle between $(a,b)$ and $(a,z)$ is in $\{0,\pi\}$.

The problem is: Given the scalar product in $\mathbb{C}$,
$$
\langle z, w\rangle=\Re(z\bar{w})
$$

> how do I derive from, for $z\in\mathbb{C}-\{a,b\}$
>   $$
> \frac{\langle a-b,z-b\rangle}{\lVert a-b\rVert\lVert z-b\rVert}\in\{\pm 1\}
> $$
>   that for some $t\in\mathbb{C}-\{0,1\}$, $z$ must havbe the form
>   $$
> z=a+t(b-a)?
> $$

The converse is quite easy (substitute and simplification), but for the direction above I have no clue technically, that is using complex calculus.
In $\mathbb{R}^2$ it would be just an orthogonal projection, but I'm looking for a solution without vectors.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $v=a-b,\, w=z-b$ and assume $w=re^{\theta i}v$ with $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$. Calculate $\langle v, w\rangle$.